# Changing default width of blocks in beamer

Tags: beamer, environments, indentation

I use a custom Beamer theme for my presentations. In my presentations I'd like to use blocks (`\begin{block}…\end{block}`). These blocks are rendered slightly too wide to fit into my theme. Is there a way how I can set the default width of blocks, e.g. to `.9\textwidth`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you do not require a new block environment with customizable width, but simply want to change the width of the original block environments, add the following to your preamble:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.9\textwidth}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.9\textwidth}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.9\textwidth}%
}{}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this but to make the block centered?  For me it sticks to the left of the page.

Comment: @mrbrich, try wrapping your block in a minipage environment, as suggested on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180462/12065. As a matter of fact, once you have your block in a minipage, it will take the size of that minipage, so you can control block size there instead of using this answer.

Answer (score 43):

You could define your own block environment with an optional parameter for its width and provide a default value such as `.9\textwidth`.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][.9\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Standard}
  Normal block
\end{block}
\begin{varblock}[4cm]{New block}
  Variable width, here 4cm
\end{varblock}
\begin{varblock}{New block}
  If no width was given, .9\textbackslash textwidth will be used
\end{varblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: variable blocks example]

I posted this example [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2251&start=0#p8797) in 2008.

Comment: (+1) I initially provided a link to this thread. Definitively better that you answered yourself.

Comment: @chl: thanks for the link! I noticed your comment right after posting. I just remembered that earlier thread. In addition to the older post I took the chance to create and post a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll definitely remember it for when I need something like this. However, the answer which I accepted does exactly what I desired right now.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, in order to center the shortened block, one has to surround it with `\begin{cenetr}\begin{minipage}{block_width}<shortened block> \end{minipage}\end{center}`

Comment: @Dror: Well, that way one can even use the regular `block` environment ...

Comment: Thats great, but can one also do it with an alertblock? I couldn't change the code, so it fit with alertblock...

Comment: I wonder, what is the purpose of `<>`in `\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][.9\textwidth]{...}`?

Comment: @GillesBonnet It's been 6 years but I was also curious. It's probably beamer-specific thing: See the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer?lang=en)' s 'beameruserguide.pdf', it 'declares a new environment that is overlay specification-aware'.

Answer (score 2):

Using the code from Stefan Kottwitz and doing minor changes, I have this in my preamble.

```
% Variable width block
\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][0.9\textwidth]{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}% required to itemize respect the width of block
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
  \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}

% Variable width example block
\newenvironment<>{varexampleblock}[2][0.9\textwidth]{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}%
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=example text}%
    \usebeamertemplate{block example begin}}
  {\par%
  \usebeamertemplate{block example end}%
    \end{actionenv}}

% Variable width alert block
\newenvironment<>{varalertblock}[2][0.9\textwidth]{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}%
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=alerted text}%
    \usebeamertemplate{block alerted begin}}
  {\par%
  \usebeamertemplate{block alerted end}%
    \end{actionenv}}
```