# How can I connect beamer blocks with edges through the center?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, posters, tikzmark, block

#### X–Y

Since my poster is on self-stabilizing algorithms (and quite frankly, I don't have much to say about it that's appropriate for a poster), I came up with a pretty cool idea for its layout.  I'd like to set many `block`s on the page and position them absolutely, manually connecting arbitrary blocks with edges to form a graph.

#### My Attempt

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,width=36in,height=44in]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\beamertemplategridbackground[1in]

\newenvironment{node}[4]{%
  \begin{textblock*}{#2}(#3,#4)%
    \begin{block}{#1}%
      \tikzmark{#1}\ignorespaces
    }{%
    \end{block}
  \end{textblock*}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  \begin{node}{Introduction}{4in}{3in}{4in}
    What is a self-stabilizing algorithm?
    Example from paper.
  \end{node}

  \begin{node}{Motivation}{10in}{14in}{15in}
    blah
  \end{node}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \draw[overlay, line width=5mm]
      (pic cs:Motivation) -- (pic cs:Introduction);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, this unsurprisingly places the mark at the top left (where the text starts).  How can I convince it to go to the center of the block, both vertically and horizontally, so as to make a convincing graph?

Comment: I've seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96289/17423, but I'd like a solution that is a little less intrusive to the user layer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a different approach not using tikzmarks but the `remember as` feature from `tcolorbox`. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,width=36in,height=44in]{beamerposter}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}                            %new code, tcb definition
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
   enhanced jigsaw,
   colback=white,
   opacityback=0,
   opacityframe=0,
   coltitle=blue,
   #1
}

\beamertemplategridbackground[1in]

\newenvironment{node}[4]{%                         %changed code
  \begin{textblock*}{#2}(#3,#4)%
    \begin{mybox}[title=#1,remember as=#1]%
    }{%
    \end{mybox}
  \end{textblock*}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  \begin{node}{Introduction}{4in}{3in}{4in}
    What is a self-stabilizing algorithm?
    Example from paper.
  \end{node}

  \begin{node}{Motivation}{2in}{14in}{15in}
       blah
  \end{node}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \draw[overlay, line width=5mm]
      (Introduction.center) -- (Motivation.center);     %changed code
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

What I did was to create a custom tcolorbox to be used instead of the `block` environment inside your `node`s. The tcolorboxes titles are also used as `remember as` keys, so you can take advantage of the standard coordinate positioning (north, south, etc.) relative to each tcolorbox.