# Connecting values in table from one column to another with a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am struggling with a table in LaTeX, where I want to draw lines inside the table environment. My goal is something like this where lines connect values from the first to values from the second column:

[image]

I will probably have to use TikZ but I couldn't find anything similar. Best I could find actually is in [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528164/connecting-tables-using-multipart) without any progress. Is it even possible to do something like that?

Update: MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{threeparttable} 
            \begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
                2018 &  \multirow{2}{*}1 & 5 & 10 & 15 \\
                2019 &  \multirow{2}{*}2 & 6 & 11 & 16 \\
                2020 &  \multirow{2}{*}3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\
                2021 &  \multirow{2}{*}4 & 8 & 13 & 18 \\
                2022 &                   & 9 & 14 & 19 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{threeparttable}    
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: One *simple* solution that comes to my mind is using `tikzmark`. Please post your table into a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and we''l help you out.

Comment: I am sort of trying to understand the syntax of TikZ @SebGlav. I just updated my question above with a minimal example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a TikZmatrix:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}<--- no more needed in up-to-date distribution
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}\centering
     \begin{threeparttable} 
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
            \matrix[matrix of nodes, 
                row sep=-4pt, 
                column sep=4pt, 
                row 1/.style={font=\bfseries, text height=8pt, text depth=4pt}] (mymatr)
            {  
            Year & Header 1 (something) &  Header 2 & Header 3 & Header 4 \\[10pt]
            2018 &  & 5 & 10 & 15 \\
            & 1 \\
            2019 &  & 6 & 11 & 16 \\
            & 2 \\
            2020 & & 7 & 12 & 17 \\
            & 3 \\
            2021 & & 8 & 13 & 18 \\
            & 4 \\
            2022 & & 9 & 14 & 19 \\
            };
            \foreach \ind
               [evaluate=\ind as \indpre using int(\ind-1),
               evaluate=\ind as \indpost using int(\ind+1)
               ] in {3, 5, 7, 9} 
               { 
               \draw (mymatr-\indpre-1.east) --
               (mymatr-\ind-2.west);
              \draw (mymatr-\indpost-1.east) --
               (mymatr-\ind-2.west);
               }
            % hlines
            \draw[very thick] (mymatr.north west) -- (mymatr.north east); 
            \draw[shorten >=-4pt, shorten <=-4pt] (mymatr-1-1.south west) -- (mymatr-1-5.south east); 
            \draw[very thick] (mymatr.south west) -- (mymatr.south east); 
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{tablenotes}[para]\small
            Note: I added the headers only to show how to manage them with a Ti\emph{k}Zmatrix.
        \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}    
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really great. Is the usage of `multirow` wrong? I see you got the same result without it.

Comment: @akis No, it is not wrong in an ordinary table, but it is not used in a TikZmatrix. Thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable} 
\begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
2018\tikzmark{18} &  \multirow{2}{*}{\tikzmark{1819}1} & 5 & 10 & 15 \\
2019\tikzmark{19} &  \multirow{2}{*}{\tikzmark{1920}2} & 6 & 11 & 16 \\
2020\tikzmark{20} &  \multirow{2}{*}{\tikzmark{2021}3} & 7 & 12 & 17 \\
2021\tikzmark{21} &  \multirow{2}{*}{\tikzmark{2122}4} & 8 & 13 & 18 \\
2022\tikzmark{22} &                                    & 9 & 14 & 19 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=0.6ex}] 
([xshift=1pt]pic cs:18) -- ([xshift=-1pt]pic cs:1819) --
([xshift=1pt]pic cs:19) -- ([xshift=-1pt]pic cs:1920) --
([xshift=1pt]pic cs:20) -- ([xshift=-1pt]pic cs:2021) --
([xshift=1pt]pic cs:21) -- ([xshift=-1pt]pic cs:2122) --
([xshift=1pt]pic cs:22);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table with lines connecting cells]