# how to change the size of one block in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am preparing a presentation of proposal thesis and I need to know how I can change the size of one block in beamer. I can not use this command. I need to personalize the size for each block

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
 \setlength{\textwidth}{0.9\textwidth}%
}{}
```

Comment: [Stefan's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12551/21891) seem to exactly answer your question.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/changing-default-width-of-blocks-in-beamer