# how to change the width of a single block in beamer keeping it centered

Tags: beamer, width, block

A very similar question was already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145539/152795). Unfortunately, as it often happens, it was mistakenly marked as a duplicate of [the following question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12550/152795).

While the latter is a perfectly legitimate solution, **the former is asking how to modify a single block, which is a different question**. Since the "duplicate" question doesn't admit further answers, I ask here again (mods: feel free to undo the duplicate error and merge both questions).

---

## How to modify the width of a single beamer block, while keeping it centered?

See following sample image of what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a single instance of a regular block like the following,

```
\begin{block}{Title}
  Block contents
\end{block}
```

you can modify its width while keeping it centered by wrapping it into a centered minipage, as follows:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Title}
      Block contents
    \end{block}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

If you wish to change the default width for a class of blocks instead of a single block, see [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12550/152795).
Hope this helps!
Andres