# Center block on frame with Beamer

Tags: beamer, block

I wanted to change the block width in my presentations so, after a quick search on the website, I found the *varblock* solution : [Changing default width of blocks in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/changing-default-width-of-blocks-in-beamer)

It consists in adding :

```
\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][.9\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}
```

to the preamble. Now, in my `.tex` document, I have blocks like this :

```
\begin{varblock}[8cm]{Title}
Some content...
\end{varblock}
```

But I cannot center the block horizontally on the frame. I tried to put these three lines between `\begin{center}...\end{center}` and `\begin{centering}...\end{centering}` but the block still remains on the left side of the frame. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the shortened block is put inside a `minipage`, you can center it easily

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][.9\textwidth]{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
    \begin{actionenv}#3%
        \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
        \par%
        \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
    {\par%
        \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
    \end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}{4cm}
                \begin{varblock}[4cm]{New block}
                    Variable width, here 4cm
                \end{varblock}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I didn't think to put the block inside a minipage!

Comment: @Keili Thank you for posting your idea. I rolled back to my original version, because I think, you should post your different approach (an alternative to using a `varblock`) as an independent answer.

Answer (score 14):

If you use `minipage` as indicated by samcarter, you can use `block` and omit the `varblock` definition since `minipage` already allows for reducing the width of the `block`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}{4cm}
                \begin{block}{New block}
                    Variable width, here 4cm
                \end{block}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to my theme, but the minipage environment is messing with the space between the block header and block body. Putting it in columns solved this issue for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[T]
      \column{0.25\textwidth}
      \column{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{New block}
         Variable width, here 50%
      \end{block}
    \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```