# customize beamer block environment: underline block title

Tags: beamer, block, underline

I'm trying to define an underlined block title in beamer and I'm unable to do it. Could anybody help me with that?
I managed to customize the specific font and shape of the block title, but so far no success with the underlining.
My (successful) code is the following:

```
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\normalsize, series=\bfseries}
```

`\underline` command is not working (neither is `\ul` with the soul package)...
Any help welcome!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you provide an MWE? That way we could help you more easily.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP after one and half year still not respond to comment nor to received answers.

Comment: @Zarko that's a strange reason for closing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right.  I thought this question would never be completed as Op has not been active on this website for over a one and half year. If you think my proposal is inappropriate, I will withdraw it.

Comment: @Zarko point is the answers may be useful to others even if the OP never returns but they are hidden if you close.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, well, I vas convinced that answers after closed question stay as they were before, and that with this is only prevented that this question is periodically appears as modified. I will retract my vote for closing question when this will be possible.

Answer (score 3):

With this: (taken from here [Changing default width of blocks in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/changing-default-width-of-blocks-in-beamer))

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
    \begin{actionenv}#3%
        \def\insertblocktitle{\underline{#2}}%
        \par%
        \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
    {\par%
        \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
\end{actionenv}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sample frame title}
    This is a text in the first frame. This is a text in the first frame. This is a text in the first frame.
    {\begin{varblock}{title}blabla\end{varblock}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To just patch all blocks to have an underlined title, you can add a redefinition of `\insertblocktitle` as `\underline{\insertblocktitle}` at the start of the `block begin` beamer template.

Edit: Similarly, for the `exampleblock` and `alertblock` environments, add the same lines to the `block example begin` and `block alerted begin` beamer templates.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
    \let\oldinsertblocktitle\insertblocktitle%
    \def\insertblocktitle{\underline{\oldinsertblocktitle}}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
    \let\oldinsertblocktitle\insertblocktitle%
    \def\insertblocktitle{\underline{\oldinsertblocktitle}}%
}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
    \let\oldinsertblocktitle\insertblocktitle%
    \def\insertblocktitle{\underline{\oldinsertblocktitle}}%
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My frame}
\begin{block}{My block}
    has some content
\end{block}
\begin{exampleblock}{My block}
    has some content
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{alertblock}{My block}
    has some content
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]